# SpriteNode Perspective?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sknode

**Problem**
Trying to programatically change the `SKSpriteNode` perspective? i.e making the `bottom` of the image a greater width than the `top` of the image, or vice versa?

Cannot find any search help for this in Sprite Kit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [CIPerspectiveTransform filter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPerspectiveTransform).I believe it is possible to apply it using SKEffectNode.